# Codesys IF statement error with bit operation

Tags: if-statement, codesys, st

The compiler gives an error for the following program. I can't solve it.

This is the Codesys system writing it in ST language. I want to operate a solenoid valve using bit operation.

```
CanRx := can_getDatabox (CAN_2, 10, ADR(CanRx_data), ADR(CanRxNumBytes));
Rx_test_1 := CanRx_data[1];
Rx_test_2 := CanRx_data[2];
Rx_test_3 := CanRx_data[3];
Rx_test_4 := CanRx_data[4];

IF(Rx_test_1 & 4 = 4)THEN
  out (OUT_1_POH_CL, 1500);
  ELSE IF(Rx_test_1 & 8 = 8)THEN
  out (OUT_1_POH_CL, 0);
END_IF
```

---

Compiler error:

```
 Error: 4011:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): Type mismatch in parameter 1 of 'AND':Cannot convert 'INT' to 'ANY_BIT'  
 Error: 4024:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): Expecting END_IF_before"
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for ST's operators](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_st_expressions/) says that the comparison and equality operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `=`, and `<>` have a *higher precedence* than boolean logic operators and bitwise logic operators.

Also, in ST bitwise logic operators are `AND` and `OR` instead of `&` and `|`. Similarly, the boolean logic operators are `AND_THEN` and `OR_ELSE` instead of `&&` and `||`. (beware though, that the boolean logic operator were added to CODESYS compiler **V3.5 SP4**, if you are using an older one, they won't be available. For example, *SoMachine* uses an older one)

Additionally, the syntax for `IF` is as follows:

```
IF condition THEN
    statement1;
ELSEIF condition THEN
    statement2;
ELSE
    statement3;
END_IF;
```

But your code has `ELSE IF` instead of `ELSEIF` and your `END_IF` is lacking a semicolon. *(Though I have never had any compiler complain if I skipped that, and they themselves often omit them in their examples in the documentation)*

So, you just need to parenthesize the bitwise operation *before* the comparison. <sub>(It's the same situation in C-family languages too, which leads to unreadable expressions with too many parentheses)</sub>, replace them with valid ST operators, and fix the `ELSE IF` part.

Try incorporating those changes, like so:

(Note I also added whitespace for readability. [ST does not impose any semantics on whitespace](https://www.plcacademy.com/structured-text-tutorial/) (unlike Python, Haskell, etc) so you should use whitespace to maximize readability and maintainability). <sub>(My *personal style* is to have spaces within parentheses, not outside them - other people strongly disagree, YMMV)</sub>

```
IF ( ( Rx_test_1 AND 4 ) = 4 ) THEN

    out ( OUT_1_POH_CL, 1500 );

ELSEIF ( ( Rx_test_1 AND 8 ) = 8 ) THEN

    out ( OUT_1_POH_CL, 0 );

END_IF;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Certainly your code is easy to read.However, the problem could not be solved.
There may be a problem with the data type, but I'm not really sure about "Error: 4024: Callback_MAIN_Task (XX): Expecting END_IF_before".

Comment: @TaroNAKAMURA Is the compiler error message the same with my changes? (note the paren around `Rx_test_1 & 4`)

Comment: @TaroNAKAMURA I also corrected the `ELSE IF` / `ELSEIF` and added another semicolon. Please try my code now and report back the **exact** compiler error.

Comment: Tihs is additional error.
Error 4253:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): 'IF' or 'ELSIF' require 'Bool' expresson as condition

Comment: Error: 4024:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): Expecting ')' before '&' 
Error: 4024:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): Expecting ')' before '4'
Error: 4253:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): 'IF' or 'ELSIF' require 'Bool' expresson as condition
Error: 4024:Callback_MAIN_Task(XX): Expecting THEN before ')'

Comment: All errors are point this code line. IF ( ( Rx_test_1 & 4 ) = 4 ) THEN

Comment: There's no `&` or `|` in ST, instead you have to use `AND` and `OR` (those are bit operators. The equivalent of `&&` and `||` in other languages is `AND_THEN` and `OR_ELSE` in ST). Also, I have yet to run into a compiler that enforces a semicolon (`;`) at the end of `END_IF`, so you can ignore that

Comment: @Guiorgy I was helped by your explanation. The additional information about bit operations helped me further my studies. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it myself. I used AND instead of &, used ELSIF insted of ELSEIF. Here is the correct code.

```
Rx_test_1 : BYTE;

IF ((Rx_test_1 AND 1) =1) THEN
   statement1;
ELSIF (( Rx_test_1 AND 2) =1) THEN
   statement2;
ELSIF (( Rx_test_1 AND 4) =1) THEN
   statement3;
ELSE
   statement4;
END_IF
```